# How to run Bitcoin-Qt over RPC to another machine

Tags: bitcoin-core, wallet, bitcoind, json-rpc, spv

I have a full node running `bitcoind` on computer A.  On computer B I have `bitcoin-cli` setup to connect to computer A over RPC.  Computer A is a headless machine.  I don't want to re-download the chain on computer B.  I am currently using a wallet that can do this, but I would like to explore my options.  Sparrow wallet is capable of talking to a `bitcoind` full node, but it is written in Java.  There have been a lot of security vulnerabilities with programs written in Java, so I'd like to avoid it completely.

1. Is there a way to connect `bitcoin-qt` on computer B to computer A (running `bitcoind`) the way `bitcoin-cli` is able to connect?
2. What are some common wallets that support this feature? (trusted nodes via RPC or SPV to a `bitcoind` full node)

Here is the information I have been able to find so far:

1. [Is it possible to run both bitcoind and bitcoin-qt as backend and frontend?](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60126/is-it-possible-to-run-both-bitcoind-and-bitcoin-qt-as-backend-and-frontend)
2. [Step by step to make a SPV bitcoin node](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/95668/step-by-step-to-make-a-spv-bitcoin-node#95688)
3. https://coldcard.com/docs/ultra-quick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Andrew Chow [said](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/60126/is-it-possible-to-run-both-bitcoind-and-bitcoin-qt-as-backend-and-frontend):

> Bitcoin-qt is not just a frontend GUI or wallet handling software. It is bitcoind with a GUI.

There is a [WIP project](https://github.com/bitcoin-core/bitcoin-devwiki/wiki/Process-Separation) for separating things and make this possible, but it's still very early and not recommended for end users.

> What are some common wallets that support this feature? (trusted nodes via RPC or SPV to a bitcoind full node)

Specter Desktop do support connecting to your core via RPC. You can also install an Electrum server on the headless machine and use Electrum or any other wallet that supports this protocol.

Comment: I ended up using Electrum with the bwt plugin which runs a lightweight electrum server that connects to my node.  I am going to look into using electrum personal server as this seems to be the recommended method